# Passing variables to usercontrol inside the listview (asp.net, c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, user-controls

I want to pass some dynamic information from the `listview` to `UserControl`, but I guess I'm missing something.

.aspx page:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource"
        DataKeyNames="id_Image">
  <ItemTemplate>
       <uc1:Info Name_Lbl='<%# Bind("Name") %>'   Description_Lbl='<%# Bind("Description")%>' ID="info1"  runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

.ascx file:

```
Name:
<asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server"  />
Description:
<asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server"  />
```

.ascx codebehind file:

```
public string Name_Lbl { get; set; }
public string Description_Lbl { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    NameLabel.Text = Name_Lbl;
    DescriptionLabel.Text = Description_Lbl;  
}
```

Everything is working fine if Im trying to get value from string text like:

```
<uc1:Info Name_Lbl="Name"   Description_Lbl="Description" ID="info1"  runat="server" />
```

But when I'm trying to get value from `Datasource`, the string values in usercontrol are "null"
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks, Jim Oak

Comment: Thanks. I had exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataBinding occurs a lot later in the Control Life cycle than `Load`.

You assign your text on Load, but your control only receives the text on `DataBind`

To fix this you can set your text `OnPreRender`. This occurs after `DataBind`

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{  
    NameLabel.Text = Name_Lbl;
    DescriptionLabel.Text = Description_Lbl;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine in your code just check the code line:

```
<uc1:Info Name_Lbl='<%# Bind("Name") %>'   Description_Lbl='<%# Bind("Description"%>' ID="info1"  runat="server" />
```

You are missing the closing bracket ")" against Description_Lbl. It should be:

```
<uc1:Info Name_Lbl='<%# Bind("Name") %>'   Description_Lbl='<%# Bind("Description")%>' ID="info1"  runat="server" />
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, i made this when i created this topic.

Comment: Have you checked the datasource in the aspx code behind file? Result set has these fields "Name" and "Description" with value?

Comment: Yes, if i paste the .ascx code in itemtemplate, everything is working fine. I guess im missing something when passing the variables to usercontrol.